# Identify ACK packets from wget in Mininet

Tags: python, mininet, pox

In mininet, I was able to make a TCP connection between a server `h1` and a host `h4` in my custom POX controller `c0` as the following:

```
h1.cmd('python -m SimpleHTTPServer 80 &')
thread.start_new_thread(tcp_thread, h4)

def tcp_thread(src):
    for i in range(10):
        src.cmd('wget -O - 10.0.0.1')
        time.sleep(5)
```

`h4` requests HTTP page from the server and keeps acknowledging the server normally based on TCP standard. Here, I want to be able to force `h4` to send `ACK` packets using another path between them. I don't have a problem with forwarding or making paths but I do have an issue with how to capture or extract `Ack` packets before `h4` sending them so I can forward them as I want.

Thank you.

Comment: do you have a function to handle PacketIn?

Comment: Yes I do. it is `def _handle_PacketIn(self, event):` . How does it help you think?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a PacketIn function you can add some lines of code to catch ACK flag

```
packet = event.parsed
tcp_found = packet.find('tcp')
if tcp_found:
  if tcp_found.ACK:
    print "ACK found"
    # do your things
```

The ACK flag is a tcp attribute as stated in the POX wiki

> TCP (tcp) Attributes: ...... 
>   FIN (bool) - True when FIN flag set 
>   ACK (bool) - True when ACK flag set ......

To get those attributes we assign the tcp part of the packet to a variable using the find method, then we access the attributes using a dot (.) ex.

```
variable.attribute
tcp_found.ACK
```

Comment: Thank you very much for enlighten me.

Comment: May I ask a question: I used your suggestion which is perfect. However, you know the first packet sent from `h4` is the SYN because of the handshaking process. Thus, the PacketIN raised from `h4` indicates the incoming [SYN] packet to the switch!!

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: The question is: Is it possible to specify the type of TCP packet (ACK or SNY) in the flow rule match()? For example, I will make two identical flow rules from `src` to `dst` but differ in the type of TCP, one to forward those ACKs via a specific route and another types in different route.

Comment: Not with POX directly. matching tcp flags in a flow mod rule is available from openflow 1.5+ and above. Pox uses 1.0 I believe.

Comment: Yes, it uses 1.0 ... So there is no way to upgrade to 1.5 ?

Comment: Depends on the switch used in the network emulation environment.